# How to update flask app.config that will propagate inside a celery worker task?

Tags: python, flask, celery

#### Simple Problem

App Configuration update is not reflected in a celery worker.

#### Configuration

Currently I have this initial config on the app.

In my **config.py**

```
class AppConfig(object):
    DISABLED = False
```

and loaded in like this when the app server starts in my **app.py**.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.AppConfig')
```

#### Celery Task

In my celery task I am using this configuration to enabled/disabled it.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, name="task_example")
def task_example(self):
   if app.config['DISABLED'] is True:
       return

   # otherwise proceed.
```

Which is called inside another service.

```
class Service(object):

    def process(self):
        task_example.delay()
```

#### Testing

I updated the config to `app.config['DISABLED'] = True` inside a test which also calls for the class `Service` that call celery task `task_example`.

```
class TaskTest(TestCase):

    def test_task(self):
        app.config.update(DISABLED=True)

        service = Service()

        # Problem lies down here because when it was called
        # the `DISABLED` remain `False`.
        service.process()
```

Unfortunately, `task_example()` is still `DISABLED == False` *(enabled)*. It is possible to update it once inside the test class and propagate the changes into the celery worker?

Comment: Did you consider using `Mock`?

Comment: @kate-melnykova Hi, I never use that lib, but worth to take a look. Or maybe you can kindly link me to it? or maybe you mean using mock data?

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html
Your code ```with patch.object(app.config['DISABLED'], return_value=True) as m:
    your code
```

Comment: Note that in patching, you need to provide the full address to the object, not import name.

Comment: Looking good! let me crack it!